# How to change single-dimension json array or object into multi-dimension

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Using Javascript or jQuery how can I change single-dimension array into multi-dimension array or nested array. Please assume that the nesting can go infinite level deeper.

This is how I get the data:

```
var beforeModifiedObj = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Awesome Group',
    type: '1',
    parentID: '0',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Rockers',
    type: '2',
    parentID: '0'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Dazzlers',
    type: '3',
    parentID: '0'
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    title: 'Rock-n-Rolla',
    type: '3',
    parentID: '0'
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    title: 'Child in Level Two - A',
    type: '2',
    parentID: '1',
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    title: 'Child in Level Three - A',
    type: '2',
    parentID: '5',
  },
  {
    id: '7',
    title: 'Child in Level Two - B',
    type: '2',
    parentId: '1'
  },
  {
    id: '8',
    title: 'Child in Level Three - B',
    type: '2',
    parentID: '5',
  }
];
```

Once processed it needs to look like below:

```
var AfterModifiedObj = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Awesome Group',
    type: '1',
    parentID: '0',
    groups: [
      {
        id: '5',
        title: 'Child in Level Two - A',
        type: '2',
        parentID: '1',
        groups: [
          {
            id: '6',
            title: 'Child in Level Three - A',
            type: '2',
            parentID: '5',
          },
          {
            id: '8',
            title: 'Child in Level Three - B',
            type: '2',
            parentID: '5',
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: '7',
        title: 'Child in Level Two - B',
        type: '2',
        parentID: '1'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Rockers',
    type: '2',
    parentID: '0'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Dazzlers',
    type: '3',
    parentID: '0'
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    title: 'Rock-n-Rolla',
    type: '3',
    parentID: '0'
  },
];
```

Comment: You can accomplish this by using nested calls to `Array.prototype.reduce`.

Comment: who ever down vote this, please mind to explain the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago, I needed a similar function which I slightly adapted to meet your requirements. I commented it and hope that helps. Note in *beforeModifiedObj* element with ID 7 has a typo in parentID!

```
function findAndInsert(searchArray, toInsert) {
    // We use an internal function in order to avoid that a developer has to pass an additional
    // value to findAndInsert
    function findAndInsertAcc(searchArray, toInsert, isTopLevel) {
        var wasParentFound = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
            // Item was found => insert and create groups attribute
            if (searchArray[i].id == toInsert.parentID) {
                if (searchArray[i].groups === undefined) {
                    searchArray[i].groups = [];
                }
                searchArray[i].groups.push(toInsert);
                wasParentFound = true;
                break;
            } else if ('groups' in searchArray[i]) {
                // Recursively continue the search in the groups property
                wasParentFound = findAndInsertAcc(searchArray[i].groups, toInsert, false);
                if (wasParentFound) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // Insert into the top-level array if no item was found and we're in the top level
        if (!wasParentFound && isTopLevel) {
            searchArray.push(toInsert);
        }
        return wasParentFound;
    }

    findAndInsertAcc(searchArray, toInsert, true);
}

var afterModifiedObj = [];
beforeModifiedObj.forEach(function(next) {
    findAndInsert(afterModifiedObj, next);
});
```